# How to differentiate Split S2 from Mitral valve prolapse murmur?

Tags: cardiology, heart

If history is not available or doesn't gives a clue about the pathology, is it still possible to tell whether it is MVP or Split S2 due to pulmonary valve problems?

Both split S2 and MVP's murmur( the systolic click) seems similar.

So these sounds can't be differentiated based on just auscultatory findings?
And even if we have some peculiarities won't there be variations that sound similarly?

Tried searching net and checked Harrison principles of internal med. still not getting clue.
(MVP-mitral valve prolapse)